# cryptsetup warning message about swap file

Tags: encryption, ssd, swap

- What is this about? I need to setup some key? Or ignore it? This is
  new 17.10 installation. Swap is on, file /swapfile exists. Home
  encryption enabled, at setup.
- How about SSD installation, may be swap should be turned off? RAM is
  enougn. Anyway I don't want to crypt it, processor is too slow.

leonid@LeonidMew:~/Downloads$ `sudo update-initramfs -u`

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Invalid source device /swapfile
cryptsetup: WARNING: target cryptswap1 has a random key, skipped
```

*Update:* What means priority -1, is it turned off?

```
leonid@LeonidMew:~/Downloads$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-0                               partition   2096636 0   -1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a result of this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-initramfs-tools/+bug/1720036

It seems to just be an slightly irritating error message with no practical consequences and is safe to ignore

Answer (score 4):

After this warning the next boot fails. While booting, the system is waiting for the encrypted swap file, but unsuccessfully. After a while a command prompt appears. For the normal boot the "exit" command have to be issued.

Solution:

```sh
sudo swapoff -a
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
sudo swapon -a
```