# Problem with cryptsetup; Ubuntu doesn’t boot as usual

Tags: boot, cryptsetup, 21.04, cryptswap

Until now, my computer was booting correctly. But after restarting it in the afternoon, something happened:

- First, I get a message at booting, just before entering the cryptestup password: `cryptsetup: warning cryptswap1: couldn't determine device type`
- After booting, my computer doesn’t recognize the second screen and won’t let me change the resolution of the screen.

I didn’t change anything about cryptsetup (password…) and didn’t mount new disks.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that the two problems were not connected:

- For the first one, the solution was [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1250835/269948):

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
  sudo swapon -a
  ```
- For the second one, I just switched back from X-11 drivers to Nvidia ones.